# What is the method in rails that converts an object to HTML id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, helper

I am wondering if there is a ready-to-use helper method that produces HTML ids for object, like the one `content_tag` uses i.e. `Resource.first` becomes `"resource_1"`

It is easy to implement of course:

```
def resource_to_html_id resource
  "#{resource.class.to_s.underscore}_#{resource.id}"
end
```

But it looks like it should be already defined in Rails. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dom_id](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RecordIdentifier/dom_id) to manually create an id string (or [dom_class](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionController/RecordIdentifier/dom_class) for class strings), or [content_tag_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper/content_tag_for) (or a more specialized [div_for](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper/div_for)) to create elements with these ids/classes already defined.

Comment: Thanks! `dom_id` it is.